# Selecting single hash from array where one hash element has the highest value

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

From the following array of hashes, how can I select a single hash where `timestamp` has the highest value?

```
data = [
  {"id" => 1, "timestamp" => 1383314276, "data" => "bea7c82f-f4b2-492a-aba3-033b1a54d9d0"},
  {"id" => 2, "timestamp" => 1383314386, "data" => "64ed2ed9-763d-443f-a74e-e7f10cbe783e"},
  {"id" => 3, "timestamp" => 1383314331, "data" => "f8cfaa99-ffe0-4d88-8fac-37e4ce462d3a"}
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you can see:

```
 data.max_by{|e| e["timestamp"] }
 # >> {"id"=>2, "timestamp"=>1383314386, "data"=>"64ed2ed9-763d-443f-a74e-e7f10cbe783e"}
```

Comment: Thank you! That was quick. Will accept the answer when the time limit is over.